# Space after newcommand

Tags: spacing

Imagine I define a new command as :

```
\newcommand{\seagal}{$\sigma$-algebra}
```

and use it as follows :

```
A \seagal is defined as
```

This will produce a text where is will have "-algebrais defined as" and not "-algebra is defined as" : a space is missing. When I write

```
\mathscr{M} is indeed a \seagal.
```

though, I don't have a space and I shouldn't have one.

How could I produce a `newcommand` that handles both cases correctly ?

Comment: Ah yes, thank you!